# JSX: less redundant way to pass props

Tags: reactjs, jsx

This is probably a dumb question. I have a JSX element that I'm using as follows:

```
<Editor 
  editor={editor}
/>
```

Is there a way, similar to how ES6+ gives you the ability to just use the keys of an object if those are identical to the value, to use shorthand to pass a variable with an identical name to as a prop that it is using?

Comment: yes, you can use the spread to pass the keys of an object

Comment: Yes you can do it like so: `<Editor {...{editor}} />`

Comment: Too easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well yes you can simply use `spread` this way;

```
<Editor {...{editor}} />
```

Reference  https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html